# How do I set up secure rules for Realtime Database but yet allow new users to be registered and hashmap created?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My app requires user registration with Firebase and also stores some basic data in Realtime Database. I have enabled email verification. Here is the Registration Activity code:

```
 private void register_user(String email, String userName, String password) {
    showLoader ();
    FirebaseHelper.createUser (email, password, task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful ()) {

            //Send verification email
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseHelper.getUser ();
            user.sendEmailVerification ().addOnSuccessListener (new OnSuccessListener<Void> () {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText (RegisterActivity.this, "Verify your email by clicking on the link we have sent you.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener (new OnFailureListener () {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d ("TAG", "onFailure: email not sent: " + e.getMessage ());
                }
            });

              // PROCEED WITH NORMAL APP FLOW
            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder ()
                    .setDisplayName (userName).build ();
                user.updateProfile (profileUpdate);
                registerUserToQuickBlox (email, userName, password);


        } else {
            if (task.getException ().getClass () == FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException.class) {
                registerUserToQuickBlox (email, userName, password);
            } else {
                hideLoader ();
                Log.w ("TAG", "createUserWithEmail: failure", task.getException ());
                try {
                    if (task.getException ().getMessage () != null) {
                        String error = task.getException ().getMessage ();
                        ToastUtils.longToast (error);
                    } else if (task.getException ().getLocalizedMessage () != null) {
                        String error = task.getException ().getLocalizedMessage ();
                        ToastUtils.longToast (error);
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ();
                    ToastUtils.longToast ("Unknown error occurred");
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
 private void registerUserToQuickBlox(String email, String userName, String password) {
    QBUser qbUser = new QBUser ();
    qbUser.setLogin (email);
    qbUser.setEmail (email);
    qbUser.setFullName (userName);
    qbUser.setPassword (password);
    Log.d ("QbS", "set QB Login etc. " + qbUser.toString ());

    ChatHelper.getInstance ().signUp (qbUser, new QBEntityCallback<QBUser> () {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBUser qbUser, Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d ("QbS", "ChatHelper success. ");
            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<> ();
            hashMap.put ("userName", userName);
            hashMap.put ("email", email);
            hashMap.put ("imgURL", "default");
            hashMap.put ("qbId", qbUser.getId ());
            hashMap.put ("isPracticing", false);
            hashMap.put ("isOnline", true);
            hashMap.put ("paymentMade", false);
            hashMap.put ("level", "1");
            hashMap.put ("userType", "student"); // get input from activity_register

            FirebaseHelper.addUser (hashMap, (Void aVoid) -> {
                qbUser.setPassword (password);
                SharedPrefsHelper.getInstance ().saveQbUser (qbUser);
                User user = User.getUserFromQbUser (qbUser);
                App.Companion.setUser (user);
                //Send user to loginFragment via PracticePhrasesActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent (RegisterActivity.this, PracticePhrasesActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra ("CONNECT", CONNECT);
                startActivity (intent);

         
            });
        }
```

I have set the rules for Realtime Database as below:

```
{ "rules": {
"users" : { 
  "$uid" : {
  ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write":"$uid === auth.uid"
}}}}
```

I am facing the issue that user registration permission is being denied by Firebase with the above rules.

Any help would be appreciated. Needless to say that I am quite a newbie and have been learning on my own.

App.kt has this method

```
 companion object {
    private lateinit var instance: App
    private lateinit var mUser: User

    fun getInstance(): App = instance
    fun getUser(): User? = mUser


    fun setUser(user: User) {
        mUser = user
    }
```

Comment: Which exact operation what you perform is rejected?

Comment: New user can not be registered as I get this error: W/SyncTree: Listen at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Comment: Although existing users can login without any issue.

Comment: Is this line `App.Companion.setUser (user);` proving that behavior?

Comment: I have included the code from APP.kt which registers QBUser to QuickBlox. I don't fully understand it as Quickblox work was done by a third party. Perhaps you can shed some light. Thanks

Comment: Ok, but you didn't answer my last question.

Comment: None of the code you shared calls a Firebase API to read from the database, so it's hard to say where the error comes from in this code. Can you reproduce the problem in a single snippet of code, without the use of a `FirebaseHelper` class? If so, that will make it more likely we can help you spot the problem.

Comment: @Alex Yes App.Companion.setUser(user); populates Firebase Realtime database.

Comment: @Frank The problem is with .write.     The user is supposed to be registered with     `FirebaseHelper.createUser (email, password, task -> {` and the FirebaseHelper code is 
    `public static void createUser(String email, String password, OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> listener) {
        getFirebaseAuth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(listener);
    }`

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a single snippet of code that any of use can run to reproduce the problem, instead of adding it in the comments. I also recomment reading ;[how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there is really the best way to increase the chances we can efficiently help.

Comment: @Frank ok. Will read the link and edit the question. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this link. I tried creating an mcv example and in the process found the problem. Posting the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the code I had not posted earlier.
I had created a method 'setValidUserName()' to verify if the display name has already been taken. It tried to do this before the user was registered and hence permission was denied. The code is as below

```
   submitButton.setOnClickListener (v -> {
            //Get data
            display_name = usernameText.getText ().toString ();
            setValidUsername ();
            String email = emailText.getText ().toString ();
            String password = passwordText.getText ().toString ();
            String chkPassword = reEnterPassText.getText ().toString ();
            if (password.equals (chkPassword) && password.length () > 7 && currentUserName) {
                register_user (email, display_name, password);
            } else if (password.length () < 8) {
                Toast.makeText (RegisterActivity.this, "Password must be at least 8 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
            } else if (!password.equals (chkPassword)) {
                Toast.makeText (RegisterActivity.this, "Passwords do not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
            }
        });
    }

 public void setValidUsername() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ();
        reference.child ("users").orderByChild ("username").equalTo (display_name).addListenerForSingleValueEvent (new ValueEventListener () {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists ()) {
                    Log.d ("dataSnapshot", "dataSnapShot: " + snapshot.toString ());
                    ToastUtils.longToast ("The username already exists.\nPlease use a different username.");
                    currentUserName = false;
                } else {
                    currentUserName = true;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
      
    }
```

I have now moved this check to after registration is completed and I now prompt the user to change the display_name if it is already taken.